# 18.04 Server: Set up RAID-1 on Lenovo ThinkSystem ST50 with Onboard Hardware Controller

Tags: drivers, server, lenovo, raid

I purchased a Lenovo ThinkSystem ST50 and was hoping to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on the built in hardware raid. I have successfully created the raid 1 array in the Intel controller and when attempting to install Ubuntu Server, both disks appear rather than the raid disk itself. I am assuming there may be a driver requirement to proceed further but the manufacture does not seem to have anything specific to Ubuntu on their website.

Would anyone else have experienced the issue I am going through or have advice for proceeding?

Many thanks.